# Heroku and Liferay installation

Tags: heroku, liferay

Hi I'm trying to upload some portlet application to an Heroku server.
Someone have experience on install Liferay on Heroku?
It is possible?

Answer (score 2):

What about use the [WeDeploy.com](https://wedeploy.com/)? It's from Liferay and you can easily manager your portal instance, I think this is the best way to host Liferay in cloud.